# Java Break Builder Pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns, break, builder

If I have a class implementing builder design pattern and the methods in which I call have actually operation checks that dependent on each other , is there a way that I can break the rest of the methods execution at some point?

example

```
public class Test
{
    public Test checkOne(int one)
    {
        if(someCondition==false)
        {
            //do not continue other builder pattern checks methods (checkTwo)
        }
        return this;
    }

    public Test checkTwo(int two)
    {
        if(someCondition==false)
        {
            //do not continue other builder pattern checks methods (checkThree)
        }
        return this;
    }

    public Test checkThree(int two)
    {
        return this;
    }    
}
```

Comment: Can you please show the usage that is wrong and what you want to happen.

Comment: the operations inside the methods could be expensive such as database queries so i'm trying to do is if at least someCondition is false in some method , that i would not continue moving in the builder pattern

Comment: what i had in mind is make a global boolean variable that i would check in the beginning of each method , but i 'm not sure if this was a good design and would it be time consuming (many if statement) or not

Comment: this is a server side code, so i want everything to run as fast as possible

Comment: In your builder class, where's the method `build()`?

Answer (score 1):

What you want is not possible the way you have modelled it as the method can only have one return type, regardless of the condition (unless you are going to cast the result).

Also what you are doing does not really make sense in terms of a builder. The job of a builder is to collect the data necessary to construct an object before its is built. It shouldn't do anything with the data until build is called. What if your conditions have changed between Check1 being called and the final object being built?

What you want may be possible depending on how the condition is determined. If you are setting something on the builder to set this condition then you might be able to do something like this pseudo code:

```
public class Builder
{
    bool condition=false;
    bool condition2=false;
    int check1 = 0;
    int check2 = 0;

    public ConditionalBuilder WithCondition()
    {
        condition = true;
        return new ConditionalBuilder(this);
    }

    public Builder Check1(int value)
    {
         check1 =value;
         return this;
    }

}

public class ConditionalBuilder : Builder
{
    public ConditionalBuilder Check2(int value)
    {
         check2 = value;
         return this;
    }

    public ConditionalBuilder2 WithCondition()
    {
        condition2 = true;
        return new ConditionalBuilder2(this);
    }

}

public class ConditionalBuilder2 : Builder
{
    public ConditionalBuilder2 Check3(int value)
    {
         check3 = value;
         return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: In Java functions can have many different return types by using the exception mechanism.

Comment: `ConditionalBuilder : Builder` - C++ here in Java? :)

Comment: @BenjyKessler throwing an exception is not a different return type, its an exception. Good luck trying to use a fluent builder pattern if the methods throw exceptions...

Comment: @SashaSalauyou Java has inheritance if I recall correctly :)

Comment: Depends on the source of the error. If the error is generated by user error (i.e. bad arguments) then it makes sense to throw an exception.

Comment: @BenjyKessler absolutely. But the point was that in Java methods cannot have different return types except for returning a type that is derived from the return type or implements the return type (but accessing the methods on the derived type will require a cast on the client side, as I pointed out)

Comment: oK lets make the problem clear again , in my server side code in almost all of my APIs i have database checks according to the data the client sends me , but these inputs are very common to arrive for example the userId and vehicleId and sometimes vehicleLicenseId and sometime other parameters, what i want to do is check when ever i make almost the same database queries on these parameters that for any reason an api should not continue cus the userId is not authorized or the vehicle does not belong to the user..eg , so i want to make this encapsulated and handled from the same place

Comment: I added another anbswer with a different option. might be more suitable. I think calling it a builder when it is not building anything caused the misunderstanding

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
checkOne() {
  if (fail) { throw new IllegalStateException();}
  ...
}

checkTwo() {
  if (fail) { throw new IllegalStateException();}
  ...
}


Usage() {try{ checkOne(); checkTwo();} catch (IllegalStateException e) {}
```

Comment: well throwing an exception is a good idea, but do you think it would be time consuming code(throwing exception) in server side ?

Comment: If throwing an exception is too time consuming then write your code in C and not Java. The overhead of Java greatly outweighs the overhead of Exceptions in Java.

Comment: actually the problem arises from in the beginning of almost all of my routes i have similar checks and i don't want to write duplicate code in every route so i try to make this encapsulated as possible

Comment: so what do you think in your opinion should be faster throwing exception or repeated if statements inside each builder method ?

Comment: You can extract if(fail) throw to a function call preconditions or something and always call that first.

Comment: The if statements will probably be marginally faster but the difference will be so minute that there will be no noticeable difference (remember the throw only happens when there is an error). On the other hand bad code has an extremely high overhead and global booleans are bad code.

Answer (score 0):

In builder pattern, you don't need to perform actual execution on chained setter methods. You can first just collect all parameters passed in builder setter methods, and check conditions in `build()`:

```
public class TestBuilder { 

    List<Integer> parameters = new ArrayList<>();  

    public Test checkOne(int one) {
        parameters.add(one);
        return this;
    }

    public Test checkTwo(int two) {
        parameters.add(two);
        return this;
    }

    // ....

    public BuilderResult build() {
        BuilderResult result = new BuilderResult();
        for (int p : parameters) {
            // condition = ...
            if (!condition) {
               break;
            } else {
               result.setParameter(p);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Actual usage of Builder pattern:

```
BuilderResult result = new TestBuilder().setOne(1).setTwo(2).build();
```

Comment: ok good idea again, but which is faster using a global if statement or initializing a list and adding items in it ?

Comment: Also you stated that the check function perform a lot of work and are not just setting parameters.

Comment: This depends of your class design. I'm just trying to explain that Builder pattern is not about just allowing to chain methods. First of all, it is a factory that hides actual class of returning object behind abstract type or interface, and chooses actual class depending on parameters passed.

Comment: @user2469133 sounds like you are trying to optimise prematurely. There is no point in worrying about that until you have an issue. The difference between them is almost certainly tiny and insignificant compared to your database call

Comment: yes i understand that this is not the right way to use builder pattern but as i said my problem arises from making similar checks in almost the beginning of all my routes or request API  according to the input i get from client of coarse.....and i want to make this encapsulated as possible and avoid duplicate code
@ Sasha Salauyou

Answer (score 0):

based on your comments it sounds like what you want is some validation chain. You may be better implementing this as a chain of responsibility. Something like this:

```
public interface IValidator
{
    Test Validate(Test test);
}

public abstract class ChainedValidator : IValidator
{
    IValidator nextValidator;
    public ChainedValidator(IValidator nextValidator)
    { this.nextValidator = nextValidator;}

    public Test Validate(Test test)
    {

        if (Condition())
        {
            return nextValidator.Validate(test);
        }
        return test;
    }
}

public class Check1Validator : ChainedValidator
{
    public Check1Validator(Check2Validator nextValidator) //may need additional parameters here to help check condition
        :base(nextValidator)
    {
    }

    public override Condition()
    {
        return someCondition;
    }
}
```

Then you just need to build the chain in the correct order...

```
var validator = new Check1Validator(new Check2Validator(...etc etc ...));
```

Comment: good idea also... have you read where my actual problem is , maybe you can suggest a completely different design pattern or approach

Comment: I read your problem, which is what lead me to use this approach as you can arrange your validators so that they operate in the order you require with all the compulsory check first and then the dependnet steps after in the correct order so that only the necessary steps are executed and as soon as a condition is failled then no further steps are executed.

Comment: and you should update the question to describe your problem accurately.

Comment: ok lets start from the beginning of the problem , would you use this approach in your server if you face similar problem, do you think this is the best solution (discussing)?

Comment: If this was me in the simple case I'd have a single validator class which did all of the validation and just call this everywhere. I would move to the above pattern if I needed to change the validation often or needed different validation in different places but wanted to reuse some parts of the validation as they shared common steps.